# SharePoint Services not running

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I have installed SharePoint standalone in C:.

I have choose database : data and log file path in D:\ drive.

Now after successful installation, I start configuring services,

SharePoint search service.

User profile service.

Managed meta data service.

Access service.

Font-end identity service.

I have installed SharePoint multiple time but i don't know why I am getting error in each service configuration.

Comment: Did you create the service applications first before trying to  start individual services from the central admin ? Kindly add more details to your question to help us understand your issue better.

Comment: Paste in error message and find additional errors in ULS log (default location is in <SharePointRoot>/LOGS

Answer (score 0):

1 Try to use "Central Administration -Configuration Wizards -Launch the Farm Configuration Wizard "

2 Check your log file (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS )